# How to enable clicking the top-right corner of the screen to click the close button?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, mouse, interface, window-buttons

I am trying to get this done:

- Move the cursor to the top right corner of the screen and click the close button to close a maximized window.

instead of this:

- Move the cursor to the top-right corner of the screen and then move it slightly back towards the bottom-left direction in order to click the close button.

The first one is much faster and feels more comfortable. It seems to work with some (maybe most) programs, but not with all.

Some programs where it is working: Nemo, VirtualBox, Chromium, LibreOffice (Writer, Calc, Draw, Impress), GParted, Atom, Audacity, VLC media player.

Some programs where it is not working: Nautilus, Gedit, Terminal, Firefox, Settings, Image Viewer.

How to get it working for all programs? Thanks.

I tried this extension but don't know how to configure it to close a maximized window: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1362/custom-hot-corners/

A screenshot of a maximized window in case it is needed:

[image: screenshot of a maximized window]

Comment: Do you know about Alt+F4?

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, but I am specifically looking for a solution for closing a maximized window by clicking on the top-right corner of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Install and open the [Custom Hot Corners - Extended](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4167/custom-hot-corners-extended/) GNOME extension:

1. Select your monitor on the left menu.
2. Select the top right corner tab.
3. Select `Windows-Control` > `Close window` under the `Primary Mouse Button` menu.

[Custom Hot Corners - Extended Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQTag.png)

The only drawback for me is that clicking on the corner closes the first window in the foreground even if it's not maximized, instead of completely minimizing it and then closing the next one with a second click.

Working under Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with some `gtk.css` styles. Note that this won't affect programs that set their own window titlebar styling, like Firefox, for example.

1. Create a file named `gtk.css` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0`.
2. Enter this CSS code, which removes the space to the right of the close button and makes the buttons fill the height of the window titlebar.

   ```css
   headerbar {
     padding-right: 0;
   }

   .titlebutton {
     min-width: 44px;
     min-height: 44px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```
3. Save the file, then log out and back in to apply the changes.

Comment: Sorry for the laaate reply. I've moved on to KDE and the issue is pretty much gone, except Firefox. I tried your solution for Firefox, and it works... except that I could no longer click the edge of the screen on top of a tab to switch to that tab, which is even more inconvenient. I didn't try it in gnome, so can't comment on that. Thanks.